# Error 400 bad request : Failed to initialize mongo connection

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

since approximately half an hour i'm experiencing error 400 when trying to retrieve data from Parse via the javascript sdk.

I got the following errors :

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/LocalQuestion 400 (Bad Request)
b.Error {code: 159, message: "Failed to initialize mongo connection"}
```

This affect some of my apps, but not all of them. For those which have this problem the dashboard isn't accessible. (I receive an error message saying that something went wrong.

Comment: Check wether they are online. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381992/how-to-counter-the-down-status-of-your-database-provider-parse-com for details